# Make Pycharm run the currently edited file

Tags: python, pycharm

When pressing the "run" button in Pycharm, I want to make it run the currently opened file, instead of automatically using run configs of other files and running those.

This is kind of like Eclipse. I'm used to Eclipse and not this, and so it'll cause me to make errors thinking I'm running the currently opened file when I'm not.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: press control+shift+f10

Comment: thanks. i hope the answer wasn't too obvious. it does show a run menu item in the menubar, even saying ctrl+shift+f10 hotkey next to it, but that one just opens up a list of run configs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by Pressing 
in windows

```
`cntrl + shift + f10`
```

in mac

```
cmd + shift +f10
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'm happy with this, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make the green run button do this too?

Answer (score 4):

Either press:

```
ctrl + shift + f10
```

Or right click your file name in the editor as such:
[image: Run]

And press run. Next time the green button will automatically run the current file.